# Redirect Doesn't Redirect to Specified Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I wrote this controller to redirect back to the same page, but I keep getting an error message, "This page isn't working right now" and "localhost can't currently handle this request."
Also, the URL at this point is "https://localhost:44359/PriceTool/DeleteObject", which is definitely not correct.

My view:

```
<hr />
<h5>ITEMS</h5>
<form form asp-controller="PriceTool" asp-action="AddObject" method="post">
    <span><input type="text" name="Type" value="I" readonly="readonly" style="width:20px" />|</span>
    <span><input type="hidden" name="NameSelect" value="" /></span>
    <span><input type="text" name="NameWrite" /></span>
    <span>
        <select name="Wrap">
            <option>N</option>
            <option>Y</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <span>
        <select name="Assembly">
            <option>N</option>
            <option>Y</option>
        </select>
    </span>
    <input type="submit" value="ADD ITEM" />
</form>
@foreach (var item in Model.ManifestsI)
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form asp-controller="PriceTool" asp-action="DeleteObject" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.Id" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="zero" value="@ViewBag.zero" />
                    <input type="submit" value="X" />
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Wrap)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Assembly)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
}
```

my the relevant action in my controller, "PriceTool":

```
//delete items
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult DeleteObject(string zero, int id)
        {
            if (zero is null)
            {
                zero = "000000-0";
            }

            var manifest = _context.Manifests.Find(id);
            _context.Manifests.Remove(manifest);
            _context.SaveChangesAsync();


            return RedirectToAction("Manifest", "PriceTool", new { zero });
        }
```

Let me know if you have any questions. I appreciate it, Thanks!

Comment: You didn't post the actual exception, but your code never awaits `SaveChangesAsync`. This has nothing to do with `RedirectToAction`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If U use **_context.SaveChangesAsync();** this methode for **asynchronous** and you should use like this

```
//delete items
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteObject(string zero, int id)
        {
            if (zero is null)
            {
                zero = "000000-0";
            }

            var manifest = _context.Manifests.Find(id);
            _context.Manifests.Remove(manifest);
           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


            return RedirectToAction("Manifest", "PriceTool", new { zero });
        }
```

but if you don't want asynchronous you should change to
**_context.SaveChanges();**

Answer (score 0):

The "_context.SaveChangesAsync();" was tripping the error.
Changed to "_context.SaveChanges();" and everything works.

Comment: Or you could make the action asynchronous and use `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();`. There's nothing wrong with `SaveChangesAsync`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```cs
//delete items
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult DeleteObject(string zero, int id)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(zero))
            {
                zero = "000000-0";
            }

            var manifest = _context.Manifests.Find(id);
            if (manifest == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Manifests.Remove(manifest);
            _context.SaveChanges();


            return RedirectToAction("Manifest", "PriceTool", new { zero });
        }
```